# Secure boot on vmware workstation

Tags: security, virtualbox, vmware

We want to run a non-standard OS (not linux or windows) that boots via secure boot on VMware workstation.

We can successfully do this on virtualbox, but want to work out how to do the same in VMWare

To get our real time OS running on virtualbox we enable EFI and secure boot in the system menu. We can then in the BIOS set the secure boot configuration and set the PK, KEK and DB keys.

How can we do the equivalent in VMWare workstation?